# iptables: redirecting inbound UDP to a different port, and response going out the "public" port

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, udp

I have an SNMP agent listening on a high-level port (16161) and I want to redirect traffic from the standard SNMP agent port 161.  Easy iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 161 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 16161
```

However responses appear to come from port 16161 and are dropped by linux clients.

I want to change the response's source port to 161 (this is also correct per the SNMP spec.) I added:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --sport 16161 -j SNAT --to-source :161
```

and this appears to cause responses to never leave the agent.  If I change `to-source` to any other port, i.e. 162, it works.  Or if I use `--dport 162` and have the client send the request to port 162, the response can use port 161.  Only when the PREROUTING `dport` matches the POSTROUTING `to-source` does the response fail to send from the agent.

Example, using PREROUTING `--dport 161` and POSTROUTING `--to-source 162`:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public $DEVICE_IP iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
```

tcpdump from the agent, source port is changed to 162 on the response packet (expected:)

```
$ tcpdump -n udp and port 161 or port 162 or port 16161
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:47:30.755126 IP 192.168.66.3.55843 > 192.168.9.87.161:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:47:30.787415 IP 192.168.9.87.162 > 192.168.66.3.55843:  GetResponse(41)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0="foo"
```

I can even *have* a PREROUTING and POSTROUTING rule for the same port, but the request can't come over the same port that the response will use:

```
$ iptables -t nat -L -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 313 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   142 REDIRECT   udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp redir ports 16161
    0     0 REDIRECT   udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp-trap redir ports 16161

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 313 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   168 SNAT       udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:16161 to::162
```

single tcpdump session:

```
tcpdump -n udp and port 161 or port 162 or port 16161
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

>>>>>>> made request to port 161, response over 162, OK <<<<<<<<<

19:55:10.709670 IP 192.168.66.3.51621 > 192.168.9.87.161:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:10.751607 IP 192.168.9.87.162 > 192.168.66.3.51621:  GetResponse(41)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0="foo"

>>>>>>> made request to port 162, response not sent <<<<<<<<<

19:55:20.372213 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:21.378445 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:22.380925 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:23.390915 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:24.393482 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
19:55:25.397306 IP 192.168.66.3.55108 > 192.168.9.87.162:  GetRequest(28)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0
```

How do I get my agent to accept UDP packets on and send replies on the same port using iptables?

Comment: Have you tried `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 161 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:16161` rule only?

Comment: Thanks @Tero I will try that. I was wondering if maybe REDIRECT was causing conntrack to attempt some stateful handling on the steam that was causing issues with the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tero's comment on my question, using `-j DNAT` instead of `REDIRECT` was the missing sauce.  Final solution:

in nat rules:

```
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 161 -j DNAT --to-destination :16161
-A POSTROUTING -p udp --sport 16161 -j SNAT --to-source :161
```

filter rules:

```
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 16161 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

The `--ctstate DNAT` trick [came from this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1019123/275255) so only port 161 accepts connections and not also 16161.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [alternative UDP redirector for MacOS and Linux](https://github.com/danpodeanu/udp-redirect); in addition to the usual source / target, it supports specifying the source / destination interfaces, as well as dropping martians (UDP packets arriving from unknown sources).

You could run it as:

```
./udp-redirect \
   --listen-port 161 \
   --connect-address 127.0.0.1 --connect-port 16161
```

The SNMP client would send packets to port 161, which would redirect them to port 16161; returning packets would come from port 16161, via the redirector, and be sent out from port 161.

Disclaimer: I am the author, and I am using it right now for this very post, to redirect Wireguard traffic.

Comment: That certainly seems handy if one were not using iptables. 